# MySQL multiple SELECT statements

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to use several SELECT statements in one statement. I've checked out some other questions and figured that this should work:

```
SELECT (SELECT users.fname, users.lname, posts.post
          FROM users, posts, comments
         WHERE users.userid = posts.userid)
       (SELECT users.fname, users.lname, comments.text
          FROM users
         WHERE comments.userid = users.userid
           AND posts.postid = comments.postid)
```

However, it doesn't work... help!

Comment: What's your objective with this query? Right now, there are several reasons this won't work. The subquerys are not aliases and nothing joins the two of them together (like a comma?). Please clarify - do you want all posts and all comments all at once? That doesn't fit any use case I can think of, so I'm thinking it's something else.

Comment: could you explain what you are trying to achieve that you need to use several select statements?

Comment: A subselect can only return one column.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you want a list of all users that have either posted or left a comment, UNION ALL is what you want (I changed the FROM/WHERE clauses accordingly):

```
SELECT users.fname, users.lname, posts.post
FROM users, posts
WHERE users.userid = posts.userid
UNION ALL
SELECT users.fname, users.lname, comments.text
FROM users, comments
WHERE comments.userid = users.userid
```

Comment: I've tried that too, but I get a weird error: "#1054 - Unknown column 'comments.text' in 'field list'". I'm 100% certain that the column comments.text exists.

Comment: If necessary, add a column that helps you identify which table the row came from e.g. `SELECT 'Post' AS Type, users.fname, users.lname, posts.post` and `SELECT 'Comment' AS Type, users.fname, users.lname, comments.text`